# GetAsyncKeyState creating problems with cin

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, console-application

I am currently creating a console game for school and I'm having trouble using GetAsyncKeyState for my main menu. My main menu is running in an infinite loop that only breaks once a key as been pressed. For instance I have:

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState('1'))
{   
    Play();
    break;
}
```

This, alone, works fine. The problem is that in my Play() method I have a cin statement right off that bat and the '1' from the Menu() comes into my Play(). I've tried cin.clear() to no avail, and cin.ignore(...) prevents the instantaneous change from Menu() to Play(). Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: The user has her elbow on the '1' key.  What do you expect to show up when you ask for input?  Think this through, you cannot have it both ways.

Comment: Note that you're checking the return value of `GetAsyncKeyState` incorrectly. But the issue here is that your program is rushing ahead before the user has *let go* of the "1" key. You probably should wait until keys are released before exiting the menu.

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState` reads the keyboard state even when your application doesn't have the focus. You might want to use `GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents` and `ReadConsoleInput` (or the old conio.h interface) instead to read only console inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Try this before the call to `Play()`

```
FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
```

Also, when you're using GetAsyncKeyState, you should mask out everything but the high bit, like this:

```
if ((GetAsyncKeyState('1') & 0x8000) != 0)
```

See the documentation under 'Return value' to understand why: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: This has no effect on `GetAsyncKeyState`.

Comment: @RaymondChen: When I try the following code: http://ideone.com/fAMby The characters for all the keys I press bleed over to standard input when the loop is done, including the 1.  But with the following amendment: http://ideone.com/lJyKY The console is empty after the loop.  So, what are you talking about?

Comment: @RaymondChen: Meanwhile, applying your suggestion: http://ideone.com/NtetV Is that accurate?  That doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin! Using your FlushConsoleInputBuffer idea in conjunction with checking only the high bit of GetAsyncKeyState works. Individually either only worked half the time, together they seem to work every time. I'd love to know why that's the case, but at this point I'm just happy to have the problem solved. Thanks again!

Comment: @smearedblackink: Oh yeah, I should have mentioned the part about checking only the high-bit.  Slipped my mind, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I misread the question. I thought the "1" from the menu was bleeding into your GetAyncKeyState call, but your problem is the reverse: You're trying to remove the "1" from the input before entering your menu. Flushing will work, then.

Comment: I know this is old, but for users come across this question and search for this question: There are some question about flush `std::cin`, that is different in that case because, only after you pressed "Enter" would the characters come into the `std::cin` buffer. Otherwise it remains in "console buffer". That is also a possible solution for using `std::cin` after `Sleep` command or similar.

Comment: @user202729: You can't flush `std::cin`. `std::istream` does not support that operation. It is only for output streams.